# Curtail UIImage download size from WEB

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an application that downloads images based on URL using the call:

```
img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToImage] options:0 error:&err]];
```

where URL is an image on the WEB.

I really want to curtail the amount of data transfer, so would like to reduce the file size of the download.

I was wondering if anyone has a magic way of reducing the file size of the download short of implementing a PHP server process to be the go between to take care of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "curtail", do you mean abandon the download if it's too large?  Otherwise, isn't a file whatever size it is?  You could zip it first to transfer fewer bytes, or you could resize it smaller once you get it.  I guess I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I think the only way to do that will require image data pre-processing  on server side. In other words, you can't just say to http server: "give me that picture but with smaller size".

Comment: We're working on a service, which solves exactly this problem. You provide a url to original image, we reduse it's size on the fly and deliver to the app. Here's the [link](http://pixpie.co)